# Module pattern jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module, config

I'm having a problem using the module pattern in a very dummy javascript code.

This code is working perfectly:

```
;
var test = (function () {
    var config =  {
        replacement: 'a'
    };

    var init = function () {
        $(config.replacement).click(function(){
            alert("hello world");
        });
    }

    return {
        init: init
    }
})();

$(document).ready(test.init());
```

Instead, this code is not working when I click on any link of my website:

```
;
var test = (function () {
    var config =  {
        replacement: $('a')
    };

    var init = function () {
        config.replacement.click(function(){
            alert("hello");
        });
    }

    return {
        init: init
    }
})();

$(document).ready(test.init());
```

Anyone could tell me why I can not use a jQuery object as "default" initialization of config variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(a)` is executed before DOM ready, probably when no `a` elements are accessible.

In your first example, the set was constructed after DOM ready.

You could turn it into a function instead...

```
var config =  {
    replacement: function() { return document.links; }
};
```

Comment: @user1648170 Care to link me?

Answer (score -1):

Then, Why in this example located in official jQuery website using a jQuery selector is working for the default config vars?

```
var feature = (function () {
    var $items = $("#myFeature li");
    var $container = $("<div class='container'></div>");
    var $currentItem = null;
    var urlBase = "/foo.php?item=";

    var createContainer = function () {
            var $i = $(this);
            var $c = $container.clone().appendTo($i);
            $i.data("container", $c);
        },
        buildUrl = function () {
            return urlBase + $currentItem.attr("id");
        },
        showItem = function () {
            $currentItem = $(this);
            getContent(showContent);
        },
        showItemByIndex = function (idx) {
            $.proxy(showItem, $items.get(idx));
        },
        getContent = function (callback) {
            $currentItem.data("container").load(buildUrl(), callback);
        },
        showContent = function () {
            $currentItem.data("container").show();
            hideContent();
        },
        hideContent = function () {
            $currentItem.siblings().each(function () {
                $(this).data("container").hide();
            });
        };
    $items.each(createContainer).click(showItem);
    return {
        showItemByIndex: showItemByIndex
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    feature.showItemByIndex(0);
});
```

[Official jQuery website](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/)

Comment: If you look *carefully*, you'll see that piece of code is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. Also, this isn't an answer to your question - it should be an edit to the original question.